# Converting list of dictionaries to a dataframe

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, pan

**INPUT FORMAT **

```js
[{'prediction_response': [{'CONFIDENCE': '0.95', 'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME': '1664640128037.6028', 'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME_END': '1664640799132.91', 'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME_START': '1664639456942.2961', 'ESTIMATED_PICKUP_TIME': '1664637731268.648', 'ESTIMATED_PICKUP_TIME_END': '1664638024419.029', 'ESTIMATED_PICKUP_TIME_START': '1664637438118.267', 'PROVIDER': 'Uber'}]}, {'prediction_response': [{'CONFIDENCE': '0.95', 'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME': '1664642137826.619', 'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME_END': '1664642842156.097', 'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME_START': '1664641433497.1409', 'ESTIMATED_PICKUP_TIME': '1664639622364.198', 'ESTIMATED_PICKUP_TIME_END': '1664639924583.373', 'ESTIMATED_PICKUP_TIME_START': '1664639320145.0232', 'PROVIDER': 'Uber'}]}]
```

**OUTPUT FORMAT **

| CONFIDENCE | ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME | ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME_END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.95 | 1664640128037.6028 | 1664640799132.91 |
| 0.95 | 1664642137826.619 | 1664642842156.097 |

### STEPS TAKEN

i have tried these approaches

-> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x)

-> pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x).T

### outputs of above steps

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNDAc.png)

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

Here is what would work.

#### Correct data format i.e. list of dicts:

Keep the input data dictionary in the below format:

```
data = {0: {'CONFIDENCE': '0.95', 
    'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME': '1664640128037.6028', 
    'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME_END': '1664640799132.91'},
    1: {'CONFIDENCE': '0.95', 
     'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME': '1664642137826.619', 
     'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME_END': '1664642842156.097' }
   }
```

#### Error in Data format:

Data format(list of dictionaries) you are using in your code is wrong.  . The dictionary format you are using has mismatching brackets. Use above format of data dictionary

```html
[{'prediction_response': [{'CONFIDENCE': '0.95', 'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME': '1664640128037.6028', 'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME_END': '1664640799132.91']}
{'prediction_response': [{'CONFIDENCE': '0.95', 'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME': '1664642137826.619', 'ESTIMATED_DROPOFF_TIME_END': '1664642842156.097' ]}]
```

#### The code to change dict to data frame.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).transpose()
```

[image]

Comment: yes @DataFramed , i have updated the input format and actually that is the response i cannot keep index in front although we can traverse and add it .